# Comparing NSDate objects

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, core-data, nsdate

I have a an application that uses CoreData. One of the entities contains `date` attribute which is, well... a date. I am writing a test to check if timestamp passed to class method for that entity's class is being converted to correct `NSDate`.

Here's my test code:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval ts = [now timeIntervalSince1970];
// paramDict is a dictionary with attributes and values
[paramDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:ts] forKey:@"date"];

MyEntity *myEntity = [MyEntity entityWithAttributes:paramDict inContext:testMOContext];

STAssertTrue([now isEqualToDate:[myEntity date]], @"dates were not equal");
```

This is only a snippet of the whole tests which checks if all parameters were set correctly. What's interesting though is that date assertion checks fail randomly. I presume the failures has something to do with the loss of double float precision? How should I check for date in this kind of scenario?

**update**

The timestamp is converted to date in the method like this:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[paramDict valueForKey:@"date"] doubleValue]];
[newObject setDate:date];
```

Comment: "Floating point math is not exact" [details here](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm).  You should not try to compare floating point numbers for equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the difference between your *now* date and the date of *myEntity* using

```
NSTimeInterval difference = fabs([[myEntity date] timeIntervalSinceDate:now]);
```

and compare the result to a threshold (1 second, for example). If *difference* is less than 1 second, consider both dates the same.

From the documentation of NSDate (*isEqualToDate*):

> This method detects sub-second differences between dates. If you want to compare dates with a less fine granularity, use timeIntervalSinceDate: to compare the two dates.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems like a hack. I also presume the `isEqualToDate:` method is there for a reason. Just not sure what happens if I instantiate a date from the timestamp that was produced by another date.

Comment: I think it has to do with double float precision, as you mentioned in your question. Maybe the `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` method converts the given time interval internally, which could cause the precision loss. Have you tried to use `dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:` instead? According to the documentation, it "provides the basis for all the other methods in the NSDate interface" and maybe doesn't need to recalculate the interval internally.

Answer (score 0):

`isEqualToDate` compares `NSDate` objects, but your `date` attribute seems to be a time interval? I suggest using the date type for the attribute, and sticking with `NSDate`.